# Pandas how to read csv with mixed type column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types

Here's what I want. When I run the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 1, 2, 3]})
print(df[1:].infer_objects().dtypes)
```

The result is expected: `col int64`
If I load same Dataframe as csv the results differs:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 1, 2, 3]}).to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
print(df[1:].infer_objects().dtypes)
```

I get `col object`.

Why the result differs? How should I load csv to get `col int64` in the second case?

Comment: Can you try [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html)

Comment: When I use convert_dtypes I get col string. I expect int64.

Comment: If someone is interested in solution I end up with -- I decided to use `converters` param when calling pandas.read_csv

Answer (score 0):

I think that columns axtracted using pandas' `read_csv()` function are by default columns containing strings to avoid any issue.

You can however modify the type of your column using:

```
df['your_column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['your_column'])
```

or the whole datatframe:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: The problem here is that I want to get mixed type column like I get in first case. Is there a way to read csv into mixed type DataFrame?